Finding previous answers to questions
How do I find previous answers to questions?
For example, when I need a snapping tutorial on QGIS 3.34.

You can use a search query such as:
[qgis] snapping answers:1

The square brackets [] denote a tag, snapping is a key word, and answers:1 filters only questions with answers.
You can see these definitions and a few more by clicking in the search bar at the top of the page.
Multiple tags can be defined like so:
[qgis] [snapping] answers:1

